# How to fix Pagination Error 'Buttons only showing up on the first and last page but none of the pages in between'?

Tags: javascript, html, pagination, getelementsbytagname

I am trying to paginate a list of student elements into different pages. The buttons are only appending to the first page and the last page. I would like to also append the button elements to pages 2 through 5 as well. Is there an error in my code or am I missing an element?

We have taken a look at all of the for-loops to see if there was an issue with the parameters. We have also tried changing the variable types.

```
/******************************************
Treehouse Techdegree:
FSJS project 2 - List Filter and Pagination
******************************************/

// Study guide for this project - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OD1diUsTMdpfMDv677TfL1xO2CEkykSz/view?usp=sharing
/***
   Add your global variables that store the DOM elements you will
   need to reference and/or manipulate.
***/

//Step 2: Get the elements for students and for pagination and page
// Grabs all the li Item and stores them into StudentListItem
let StudentListItem = document.getElementsByTagName('li'); 

console.log(StudentListItem.length);

//Takes the children of the li Item and stores them into ChildListItem. Aka the ul Item
let ChildListItem = StudentListItem.children;

//Makes the child item so you manipulate the elements in the DOM

let NumberofItem = StudentListItem.length;

//Step 3 & 4: Determine the number of elements that goes on one page. And 
// create the variable for the number of pages needed

const ItemPerPage = 10;

//Step 5: Create a function that determines the number of pages PagesNeeded
const TotalPages = Math.ceil(StudentListItem.length/ItemPerPage);

//Step 6: Create for- loop that deletes the display for all the items
for (var i = 0; i < StudentListItem.length; i++) {
  StudentListItem[i].style.display = 'none';
}

//Step 7: Create a function that only shows the first ten list items.
function showPage (page, ChildListItem) {
  // Loops through items to find what to hide or show
  for (let i = 0; i < StudentListItem.length; i++) {
    // shows the first 10 items in list
    if (i < (page * ItemPerPage) && i >= ((page * ItemPerPage) - ItemPerPage)) {
      StudentListItem[i].style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      // hides the rest of the 
      StudentListItem[i].style.display = 'none';items
    }
  }
};

showPage(1,ChildListItem);


// Loop to create page buttons based on number of required pages
const buttonDiv = document.createElement('div'); // creates a div for buttons
const mainPage = document.querySelector('.page'); // creating a selector for page div

console.log(mainPage);

mainPage.appendChild(buttonDiv); // appends buttonsdiv to the page
buttonDiv.className = 'pagination'; // gives buttodiv the class name pagination
console.log(buttonDiv); // logs button div to  console

const buttonUl = document.createElement('ul'); // creating unordered list
buttonDiv.appendChild(buttonUl); //append list to buttondiv


for (let i = 0; i < TotalPages; i+= 1) { // for-loop creates li and a element.
  pageli = document.createElement('li');
  const pageLink = document.createElement('a'); // a makes the buttons hyperlinks
  pageLink.className = 'active'; // activates the a link created by a variable
  pageLink.href = '#'; //puts numbers as the hyperlink text
  pageLink.textContent = i + 1; //textcontent i + 1
  pageli.appendChild(pageLink); //appends the pagelinks
  buttonUl.appendChild(pageli); // appends the buttonul to the li

  //The page = a notebook
  //The ul = pages in a notebook
  //The li = writing on the page in the notebook
  // -------------------PAGE------------------
  //            ---------UL----------
  //                  ---LI--------

  buttonDiv.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      let buttonNumber = parseInt(event.target.textContent);
      let max = buttonNumber * 10;
      let min = max - 10;
      for (let i = 0; i < StudentListItem.length; i++) {
          if (i >= min && i < max) {
              StudentListItem[i].style.display = '';
          }  else {
              StudentListItem[i].style.display = 'none';
          }
      }
  });//evernt listener

}

console.log(buttonUl);
console.log(TotalPages);
```

Real time GitHub link [is here](https://github.com/sjartemus/list_pagination_and_filtering-v1).

I expect for all of the button elements to be appended on pages 1-6.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `document.getElementsByTagName("li")` returns a *live* NodeList. [See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

A live NodeList will update itself when more `li` elements are added to the document. In this case, when the pagination `li` elements are added to the document, then are hidden when with all the other elements that are not in the current page.  When a pagination button is clicked.

---

To demonstrate this, I will show your code *(Annotations are mine)*:

```
let StudentListItem = document.getElementsByTagName('li'); // a live list
console.log(StudentListItem.length); // <-- 54 in your GitHub example
// ...
// Now create the pagination buttons:
for (let i = 0; i < TotalPages; i+= 1) {
  pageli = document.createElement('li');    // <-- Here we create a new li in the document
  const pageLink = document.createElement('a');
  pageLink.className = 'active';
  pageLink.href = '#';
  pageLink.textContent = i + 1;
  pageli.appendChild(pageLink);
  buttonUl.appendChild(pageli);

  // ...
  // add the event listener
} // End of loop for each pagination button
```

So now, if you were to check the `StudentListItem` you would find it now contains more elements. (It is a *live* list, remember)

```
console.log(StudentListItem.length); // <-- now 60 (54 original plus 6 from the pagination links)
```

### The Solution:

The solution is to not have the `StudentListItem` be a *live* list for *all* the `li` elements in the *`document`*.

I thought of three possible solutions:

1. Don't get *all* the list items, restrict it to just the original `ul`.

   For example:

   ```
   let ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
   let StudentListItem = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
   ```

   Now this is still a live list, but the pagination `li`s are not children of the `ul` that we are selecting.
2. Don't use a *live* list.

   ```
   let StudentListItem = document.querySelectorAll("li");
   ```

   Here, [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a static list that will not be updated when new `li` elements are added to the `document`.
3. Just use the precalculated length when hiding the items. (`NumberofItem`)
   So instead of

   ```
   for (let i = 0; i < StudentListItem.length; i++) {
        // Hide items...
   ```

   do

   ```
   for (let i = 0; i < NumberofItem; i++) {
   ```

   This restricts the number of hidden `li` elements to just the original ones.

---

Another thing I noticed was the event listener was attached to the container around the pagination buttons, not the buttons themselves. This can be fixed by replacing

```
buttonDiv.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
```

with

```
pageli.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
```

---

<sub>The reason the buttons show up on the first page is because they were not arround to be hidden when the first `showPage()` function is called.  The reason the buttons show up on the 6<sup>th</sup> page is because they are the 55-60<sup>th</sup> `li` elements, which happen to fall into the 6<sup>th</sup> page.</sub>